# How can I solve this error: TypeError: Cannot interpret '<attribute 'dtype' of 'numpy.generic' objects>' as a data type, I have also updated the numpy

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda

```
C:\Users\Hamza Laptop\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\deprecation.py:87: FutureWarning: Function get_feature_names is deprecated; get_feature_names is deprecated in 1.0 and will be removed in 1.2. Please use get_feature_names_out instead.
  warnings.warn(msg, category=FutureWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "final_impliment.py", line 193, in <module>
    'label': a
  File "C:\Users\Hamza Laptop\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 348, in __init__
    mgr = self._init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Users\Hamza Laptop\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 459, in _init_dict
    return _arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Users\Hamza Laptop\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 7359, in _arrays_to_mgr
    arrays = _homogenize(arrays, index, dtype)
  File "C:\Users\Hamza Laptop\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 7669, in _homogenize
    raise_cast_failure=False)
  File "C:\Users\Hamza Laptop\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4149, in _sanitize_array
    value, len(index), dtype)
  File "C:\Users\Hamza Laptop\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py", line 1201, in construct_1d_arraylike_from_scalar
    subarr = np.empty(length, dtype=dtype)
TypeError: Cannot interpret '<attribute 'dtype' of 'numpy.generic' objects>' as a data type
```

Comment: Please see Stack Overflow's [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  For starters, showing some code would be helpful.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.